# How to use older version of Java (not the default) with Maven project on NetBeans 8

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I need to use Java 6 but NetBeans is not using it even after all the configurations I made. It keeps running Maven with the Default that is Java 8 for my IDE. The same configuration runs well on Eclipse so I don't get what I am doing wrong.

I don't want to define the compiler in the nb-configuration.xml since I would have to commit the file. I would expect NetBeans to get it right from the POM.

General information:

- I am using NetBeans 8.0.1 (fully updated) running on Java 8
- NetBeans 8 needs JDK 7+ in order to work
- Using Maven 3.2.3, but the embedded (Maven 3.0.5 didn't work as well)
- All Maven plugins are up to date

To reproduce simply create a Maven project of any type in NetBeans. In my case I tried with Java, Web and EJB but none worked.

The following image shows that the JDK is properly added to the IDE.

**Tools > Java Platforms**

JDK 1.6 is added.

[image]

POM configurations that I have tried:

**Properties**

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

**Compiler Plugin**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**Enforcer Plugin**

Enforcing Java 6 gives the following error:

```
Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-25 is not in the allowed range [1.6,1.7).
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
```

Configuration for the enforcer:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>enforce-versions</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireJavaVersion>
                            <version>[1.6,1.7)</version>
                        </requireJavaVersion>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**Test code for Java 6**

The following code should *not* compile:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class JavaVersionChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Files.class); // Java 7 API
        System.out.println("Time: " + LocalTime.now()); // Java 8 API

        // Print Java version
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    }

}
```

**Test Output**

The test code compile with Java 7 and 8 API, but only Java 6 should be accepted.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building java6_project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ java6_project ---
class java.nio.file.Files
Time: 19:24:05.997
1.8.0_25
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.610 s
Finished at: 2014-11-21T19:24:06-02:00
Final Memory: 6M/123M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**JDK 6 should be detected by the IDE**

[image]

Comment: please note that [1.6,) is satisfied with 1.8 as well.

Comment: also I'm not sure what you mean by "portable", is that "I don't want to do any IDE specific setup at all"? Then there is no solution to your problem. However there are ways to make the setup once and share it across your projects and coworkers (so that it's setup just once). If you read what is generated in nb-configuration.xml, it will give you a hint.

Comment: @mkleint For your fist comment, I edited the question with the right conf. tx.

Comment: @mkleint As for your second comment, plug-ins and other stuff are there for this purpose, to avoid binding configuration of IDE with the product. In Eclipse a simple property configuration solves all my problems for this question, and I wanna know why NetBeans is not working the same way.

Comment: @BonanzaOne In eclipse it works because of the m2e plugin but as far as I know NetBeans supports this feature too. In eclipse you have to run "update project configuration" to apply settings like this, maybe you need to do something similar in Netbeans.

Comment: @kapep Didn't work. I tried also closing the project, reopening it and also reentering netbeans.

Comment: I think the enforcer version is still wrong and allows everything including and above 1.6. It should be something like `[1.6,1.7)` to exclude higher versions. https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html

Comment: @kapep You are correct again, but now that I defined it the right way, it says that the JDK is version 8, and throws an Exception. The enforcer only prevents Maven from compiling with the wrong version, but I still can't make it to use the 1.6 version =(

Comment: I don't have much more ideas. You could try to import the project files as a new maven project and see if the jdk version gets used. If not would I guess the pom is broken (but not enough to break the build). Are you using profiles anywhere or get any seemingly unrelated warnings? Btw there is also http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/ to prevent accidental api usage of newer jdk versions, which can make the app fail at runtime

Comment: @kapep Same POM works fine in Eclipse. No warnings at all in NetBeans. You can try the configuration, it is very short.

Comment: hat exactly does this mean? "In Eclipse a simple property configuration solves all my problems for this question, and I wanna know why NetBeans is not working the same way".. have you checked the nb-configuration.xml content? the comments there explicitly say that you can take that ONE property (with the specified JDK) and copy it to your pom and make it work that way as well.. All this question looks a bit like trolling to me..

Comment: @mkleint I've looked quite a bit for a solution and must say this property is not well documented - actually, it seems it is not documented at all. If you google `"netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform"` the only results a few bugzilla issues where it's mentioned in the discussion and some github projects that use it. It kind of makes me wonder if this property is even something official. The Eclipse integration with Maven is way better, m2e picks up properties/version config of the maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: @mkleint I've noticed you are a netbeans commiter and worked on this topic, may I ask if you know the reason why a special property is used and the maven-compiler-plugin version property is ignored? (genuine question, I've read a few discussions but maybe missed the right one) I got the impression that netbeans does take version of the enforcer plugins into account, why not just use `maven.compiler.source` too? Anyway, this post is a valid question and will probably help a lot former eclipse users, so please don't accuse anyone of trolling.

Comment: Well, typically you cannot deduce much from the source/target level (eg. these don't have to match). It's used (for the IDE's compiler and apis) but not for the decision what JDK to pick. Any property that ends up in nb-configuration is more or less official. The enforcer rule is not used because of ranges I believe  and the randomness  resulting from it (or it was not used that frequently at some time and the decision was not reevaluated later). Might be worth filing as enhancement request I guess.

Comment: re: trolling. What has to be noted first is that selection of JDK does work and always worked with comfortable selection from the UI. So I'm not sure how that can affect the majority of former eclipse users. The current question deals with the fact the the additional netbeans specific file is not wanted in version control. That's off-the beaten track usecase but it's supported. My suggestion to read the nb-configuration.xml file content was ignored and more complaining and bashing of netbeans followed. Please note that I'm not working on netbeans anymore and answer in my free time.

Comment: @mkleint oh I've missed the part where you first suggested to look in the file, the reaction makes more sense then. About eclipse users: The thing is, in eclipse you don't set the version in the UI because it would reset to the version defined in the pom (or the default) on update. I think the approach of using target/source to set the execution/classpath java version works well enough for most cases, also without commiting ide files. The actual jre/jdk version used can be different though but a warning informs you about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by the comments I made the configuration work using a **hint** property, which is also very well documented in the generated *nb-configuration.xml*.

Configuration added to the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>JDK_1.6</netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>
</properties>
```

As I understand the compile version for NetBeans needs to be set by a proprietary parameter, which is very simple to set up.

Useful nb-configuration.xml details:

> Properties that influence various parts of the IDE, especially code
>   formatting and the like.  You can copy and paste the single
>   properties, into the pom.xml file and the IDE will pick them up. That
>   way multiple projects can share the same settings (useful for
>   formatting rules for example). Any value defined here will override
>   the pom.xml file value but is only applicable to the current project.

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by an old entry in nb-configuration.xml

Just adding this property to pom.xml as suggested by @BonanzaOne did not worked for me.

By changing

```
<netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>JDK_1.6.0_34</netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>
```

to

```
<netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>JDK_1.6</netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>
```

directly in nb-configuration.xml, Netbeans picks the existing JDK 1.6 automaticaly.